# How to sync two devices as paranoidly as possible?

Tags: wi-fi, sync, bluetooth, offline

While I could use Google or in my case Samsung to synchronise my tablet and phone, I'd prefer a solution that neither requires Internets access nor trusting a third party. So how can I synchronise my devices offline, including sms and other non-file things, and without using a PC?

Both devices are rooted and I wouldn't mind<sup>♤</sup> paying<sup>♤</sup> for a solution

<sup>♤</sup>not too much

Answer (score 0):

Connect both devices to a PC and simply copy all files from the first device to the second one and vice versa. So all files are in sync on both devices.

If you like to do that automatically then look up some sync app/program that will do it for you.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, I also mean things that are not files, such as SMS. And for files alone one can also directly use e.g. Bluetooth file transfer without a PC

Comment: Apart from the fact that bluetooth is in fact really slow. SMS and such are also stored inside files: Databases that contain all the information in a large table with all information you need. To sync those you need to access your secured (SMS) storage which is not possible without system or root permissions. So either stick to the manufacturer's way of getting those messages or root your device and set up a script that will copy those databases, merge them and put them back where they belong.

Comment: So.....what app/program can sync automatically offline?

Comment: I don't know any right now but I will do a quick search for you.

Comment: I found an app just for you, but it doesn't work offline. It's called `mysms`. If your are familiar with shell scripts you may like to copy the database `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` from both devices and merge them together. After that just copy both files back to both devices. Also try to keep a backup in case something may go wrong.